# Problems with jQuery and testing checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have some little problems about testing if a checkbox is checked with jQuery. I've a table and in every row a checkbox with the same ID.

```
<td><input id="hp" type="checkbox" aria-label="..." checked></td>
```

This is the jQuery function:

```
$('#hp').bind("click", function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            alert("check");
        } else {
            alert ("unchecked!");
        } 
});
```

But it only works with the first row of table. Any suggestions?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique on document context...

Comment: `every row a checkbox with the same ID` ID should be unique use `class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like

```
<td><input id="hp" type="checkbox" class='checkBoxClass'></td>
```

and

```
$('.checkBoxClass').bind("click", function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            alert("check");
        } else {
            alert ("unchecked!");
        } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below :

> HTML Code

```
<td><input id="hp" class="hp" name="hp[]" type="checkbox" aria-label="..." checked></td>
```

> Javascript

```
$('.hp').bind("click", function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        alert("check");
    } else {
        alert ("unchecked!");
    } 
});
```

I hope it work for you.

Comment: remove `#` ID in the first place. Also, know your JS properties! `this.checked` is quite enough.

Answer (score 0):

how about?

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind("click", function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            alert("check");
        } else {
            alert ("unchecked!");
        } 
});
```

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/n2cgnodp/

Answer (score 0):

So, ID **must be unique**, if you use `#hp` on multiple elements, jQuery / JS will return only the first one!

**Use** `.`**class** instead:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xurumu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

```
<input class="hp" type="checkbox" aria-label="..." checked>
```

```
$(".hp").on("change", function(){
   alert(this.checked? "YEY!" : "Not checked :( ");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If there is no way other than giving same `id` to each checkbox then go for following code:

```
$('body #hp').bind("click", function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            alert("check");
        } else {
            alert ("unchecked!");
        } 
});
```

Here `$('body #hp')` will give you all the elements with same `id` as `hp`

Comment: why do something that is not good?Having same ID is not good practice

Comment: `body #hp` is not needed, only `#hp` suits quite well. Also it's incorrect to use multiple #'s in a single page > **the main issue**! :)

Comment: @Pekka but if the `html` code is not under our control or if its coming from a service call then how to deal with such situation. Why `jQuery` support above code?